# Ruby Bundle Install Not Working. Can't Install Racc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

Using my macOS Monterey v12.6, I'm trying to run `Bundle Install` in my Ruby on Rails projects and it stops working.

This is the message I get when I get after it stops.

```
Fetching racc 1.6.0
Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/racc-1.6.0/ext/racc/cparse
/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20220930-1192-12lr3he.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_block_call()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
(RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_link0'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:782:in `try_func'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1069:in `block in have_func'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
        from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1068:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/racc-1.6.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/racc-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/racc-1.6.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing racc (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.6.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 6.1.5, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 6.1.5, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 6.1.5, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 6.1.5, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri was resolved to 1.13.3, which depends on
              racc
```

Ruby Version:

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

I tried running `rails -v` and this is the response to that:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
        7: from /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        6: from /Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        5: from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `activate_bin_path'
        4: from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `synchronize'
        3: from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `block in activate_bin_path'
        2: from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:232:in `finish_resolve'
        1: from /Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:175:in `ensure in require': CRITICAL: RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.owned?: before false -> after true (RuntimeError)
```

Anyways, Rails in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.0.4.6'
```

I already tried solving the issue by doing the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460196/problem-with-bundler-using-rails-mac-user/73913105#73913105) and it didn't solve it.

Does anyone know what's happening and how shall I solve it?

Comment: do you see the error message in that backtrace that says "You have to install development tools first"? Well that's the big clue. Your XCode is either not installed or not up to date. So Google MacOS install XCode, and you will find it on the App Store and you'll find instructions from Apple on how to install or get the latest version,

Comment: Like I said, I did followed that same solution from the hyperlink I provided and didn't worked. Maybe I'll need to restart the computer and everything but I installed XCode.

Comment: what does mkmf.log say - it's referenced in your error log? Also did you really install XCode dev tools via command line? I had a similar problem and people referenced me to "install xcode", which I did, but I never did the critical "xcode-select --install" ... I know you said you followed the instructions that say this, but again - been there, overlooked that myself :)

Comment: @tkhobbes thanks for bringing up a good point. I did run xcode-select --install. In my case, I looked into the log and turns out I had to run the additional command xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch in order to finally make it work.

Thanks for the advice and understanding the issue I had though.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing XCode dev tools via the terminal running command `xcode-select --install`, I went to System Preferences -> Software Update and updated ran the updates to the OS shown after installing XCode.

It is important to make sure Developer Tools have the authorization to use Terminal.

[image: Security & Privacy]

After updating macOS, run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` and you'll finally be able to successfully run `Bundle Install` and `Bundle Update` in your Ruby projects.